# Show missing values for user

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a table in Excel that looks like this

```
role    user
a       Joe
b       Joe
c       Joe
a       Frank
```

And second table

```
role
a
b
c
```

Is it possible to list missing role for each user like in example?

```
Frank   b    c
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `b` and `c` that are missing for `Frank`?

Comment: Ups, my mistake. I correct it

Comment: Would you have a master list of roles to key off of, or is it just whatever distinct roles can be pulled from the first column?

Comment: It will be master list

Comment: One approach would be to create a third table that is the cartesian product of the first two and compare the first table to it. If there is no match, then output the missing role next to the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. This was much harder than expected. Not the most elegant solution. Requires that `user` column be sorted first so all users are together.

Probably won't work if `role` is more than one word XD

```
Sub wert()

Dim roles
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim fRow As Long
Dim user As String
Dim except As String
Dim list As String

user = Application.InputBox("which user?") 'prompt for user

With ActiveSheet

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    roles = .Range("D2:D4") 'change range as needed

    With .Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
        Set f = .Find(user, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) 'search for user
    End With

    If Not f Is Nothing Then fRow = f.Row 'if found

        list = .Cells(fRow, 1)
        For i = fRow To lastRow
            If .Cells(i + 1, 2) = .Cells(i, 2) Or .Cells(i - 1, 2) = .Cells(i, 2) Then
                list = list & .Cells(i, 1) 'add role to list
            'Debug.Print list
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        For Each e In roles
            If InStr(list, e) > 0 Then
            Else
                except = except & " " & e 'if role not found in list, then add it to string
            End If
        Next

    .Range("F1").Value = user & ": " & except 'change range if desired

End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @ForwardEd you alive?

Comment: week of internet crash, then away for the past 5 day, will be away again for the next 3 weekends, job interview, potential job interview...attention has been elsewhere.

Comment: @ForwardEd oh, I am sure they will love you. Just show them your `sumproduct` skills!